# in ansiblePlaybook plugin how to add multiple inventory files

Tags: jenkins, ansible, cicd

This is ansible playbook. I have two inventory files. How can I add those two in the below command?

ansible-inventory-file1
ansible-inventory-file1

```
 ansiblePlaybook(
        playbook: 'ansible/playbooks/stop-start.yml',
        inventory: 'ansible-inventory-file1',
        credentialsId: 'test-ssh',
        hostKeyChecking: false,
        extraVars: [
        action: "stop",
        deploy_env: "${Environment}",     
      ],
```

Comment: Welcome. I like your question. You should remove "Can someone help me out please?" from your question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Also, you should fix the typo in your question. Then you'll have a good start :-)

Answer (score 2):

Put the files into a directory

```bash
shell> tree ansible-inventory/
ansible-inventory/
├── file1
└── file2

0 directories, 2 files
```

Use this directory

```yaml
         inventory: 'ansible-inventory',
```